# Symfony Authentification Users Form Login

Tags: php, security, symfony, fosuserbundle, hwioauthbundle

I have symfony with FOSUser and HWIO Bundle. And before I have authentication only HWIO(only social network), but now I need with form authentication, with email and password. I create form registration and authentication action, and when user registration, by form, user have email and password (sha1), begin user enter email and password in form login

```
The controller must return a response (null given). Did you forget to add a return statement somewhere in your controller?
```

this is my security, I create encoders and create providers 'chain_provider' he is use 'user_dev', create admin_secured_area for 'chain_provider' and I know understand why not work, help please. what I need to do for registration user by email and password ? What am I doing wrong?

```
security:
 encoders:
    FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512
    UserBundle\Entity\User:
        algorithm:        sha1
        encode_as_base64: false
        iterations:       1
    Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

providers:
    fos_userbundle:
        id: fos_user.user_provider.username
    my_custom_hwi_provider:
        id: app.provider.user_provider
    chain_provider:
        chain:
            providers: [user_dev]
    user_dev:
        entity: { class: UserBundle\Entity\User, property: email }


firewalls:

    main:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
        oauth:
            resource_owners:
                facebook:           "/login/check-facebook"
                vkontakte:             "/login/check-vkontakte"

            login_path:        /login
            failure_path:      /login

            oauth_user_provider:
                #this is my custom user provider, created from FOSUBUserProvider - will manage the
                #automatic user registration on your site, with data from the provider (facebook. google, etc.)
                service: app.provider.user_provider

        logout:       true
        anonymous:    true

    admin_secured_area:
        pattern:    ^/auth/
        anonymous: ~
        form_login:
            provider: chain_provider
            login_path: /auth/login
            check_path: /auth/login_check
        logout:
            path:   /auth/logout
            target: /
            invalidate_session: false

access_control:
    - { path: ^/auth/login$, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

this is my SecurityController:

```
  /**
   * @Route("/auth")
   */
  class SecurityController extends Controller
  {
/**
 * @Route("/login", name="login_route")
 * @Template()
 */
public function loginAction()
{
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    $session = $request->getSession();

    $securityContext = $this->container->get('security.context');
    if ( $securityContext->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY') ) {
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('get_all_posts'));
    }

    if ($request->attributes->has(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR)) {
        $error = $request->attributes->get(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
    } else {
        $error = $session->get(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
        $session->remove(SecurityContext::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
    }

    return array(
        '_last' => $session->get(SecurityContext::LAST_USERNAME),
        'error'         => $error,
    );
}

/**
 * @Route("/login_check", name="login_check")
 */
public function loginCheckAction()
{
    // this controller will not be executed,
    // as the route is handled by the Security system
}
```

this is my template

```
<h2>LOG IN</h2>
    <form id="artel-list" method="post" action="{{ path('login_check') }}">
        <div>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <div><label for="username">Email</label></div>
                    <div class="indent"><input type="text" name="_username" id="username" value="{{ _last }}"/></div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div><label for="password">Password</label></div>
                    <div class="indent"><input type="password" name="_password" id="password" value=""/></div>
                    <a class="popup-link-1" href="">Forgot your password?</a>
                </li>
                <li class="next">
                    <button type="submit" id="sign-in" class="artel-button">Log in</button>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </form>
```

help please

Answer (score 0):

You don't appear to actually be rendering the login form. I haven't used this specific bundle, but I have implemented my own, and I return:

```
    return $this->render(
        'MySecurityBundle:Security:login.html.twig',
        array(
            // last username entered by the user
            'last_username' => $session->get(SecurityContextInterface::LAST_USERNAME),
            'error' => $error,
        )
    );
```

Try returning an actual render out of the loginAction function.

Comment: I try but not help, still have:
`The controller must return a response (null given). Did you forget to add a return statement somewhere in your controller?`
        `return $this->render(
            'PillsBundle:Security:login.html.twig',
            array(
//            '_last' => $session->get(SecurityContext::LAST_USERNAME),
            '_last' => $session->get(SecurityContextInterface::LAST_USERNAME),
            'error'         => $error,
        ));
    }`

Comment: Short of removing loginCheckAction altogether, I have no other suggestions for you.